# Time and work question involving two products and two machines

Tags: arithmetic, word-problem

Two products A and B can be made on either of the two extrusion machines M1 or M2. The time in minutes taken by these products according to the machine used, are as given below. Assume a day has 8 working hours.
        for A: M1 takes 8 min and M2 takes 10 min
        for B: M1 takes 6 min and M2 takes 6 min

If A and B are produced in the ratio 3:1, then what is the maximum total of products A and B that can be produced in a day?
a. 120.  b. 160.   c. 116   d. none of these

If A is produced only on M1 and B only on M2, then what is the unutilised time on M2 in a day, if A and B are produced in 1:1 ratio?
a. 20 min.  b. 60 min.  c. 150 min   d. none of these

I tried solving the first one and somehow got 120 by using two variables x and y and eliminating options by some assumptions. I get the second answer to be 120 min but the answer says it's 150 min. It would be helpful if somebody will elaborate on how these problems are to be solved. Are there any specified methods or steps. Also, while searching for some help on the internet, i found things 
related to linear programming. Is that related to this problem?

Comment: A and B are produced in the ratio 3:1. For a, b and c these means you have to produce (90A and 30B) or (120A and 40B) or (87A and 29B). However, you cannot produce more than 60A (since 8 hours = 480 minutes). So, for the first question, the answer should be (d).

Comment: You didn't consider both the machines running for the whole time ie assuming both the machines M1 and M2 are working to produce A for the whole day, then the maximum number of A produced will be 60+48=108. So you can eliminate the option with 160 (120 A and 40 B) since 120 A can't be produced in a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up as a Linear Program (although I'm not sure if it is the only way to solve it).

Let $a1, a2$ be the number of A produced on $M1$ and $M2$ respectively.
Let $b1, b2$ be the number of B produced on $M1$ and $M2$ respectively.

The setup is:

maximize:
$\quad\quad Z = a1 + a2 + b1 + b2$
subject to:
$\quad\quad a1 +   a2 - 3b1 - 3b2 = 0$
$\quad\quad 8a1 +  0a2 + 6b1 + 0b2  <= 480$
$\quad\quad 0a1 + 10a2 + 0b1 + 6b2  <= 480$

You can use the online calculator at http://comnuan.com/cmnn03/cmnn03004/
with the following setup:

max
$1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1$

$1 \;\;\; 1 \;\; -3 \; -3  \quad \;\; 0 \quad 0$
$8 \;\;\; 0 \quad \;\;  6 \quad \;\; 0 \;\;-1 \quad 480$
$0 \;\;10 \quad \; 0 \quad \;\; 6 \;\; -1 \quad 480$

Hope this helps.

Further Clarification:
You have 2 machines $M1$ and $M2$. Each machine is available for 480 minutes each.

Let $a1$ and $a2$ be the number of units of A produced on $M1$ and $M2$ respectively.

Let $b1$ and $b2$ be the number of units of B produced on $M1$ and $M2$ respectively.

1) The time used to produce $a1$ units on $M1$ is 8*a1
2) The time used to produce $b1$ units on $M1$ is 6*b1
3) The time used to produce $a2$ units on $M2$ is 10*a2
4) The time used to produce $b2$ units on $M2$ is 6*b2

Since $M1$ can only be run for 480 minutes, the time used to produce a1 units of A and b1 units of B cannot exceed 480 minutes. That is, any values of a1 and b1 that need more than 480 minutes to produce is an "infeasible" solution (i.e. invalid).

That's the reason for the equation: $\quad\quad 8a1 +  0a2 + 6b1 + 0b2  <= 480$
This ensures that only "valid" solutions are considered.

Comment: 8a1+0a2+6b1+0b2<=480
0a1+10a2+0b1+6b2<=480. I am not sure what you mean by the two statements. Also, i am not very familiar with lpp, but it ll do if you just explain it to me what these two lines stand for. I understand the rest.

Comment: if you produce a1 and b1 on M1, you use 8a1 + 6b1 minutes. This cannot be more than 480 minute (8 hours). So, we have $8a1 + 6b1 \le 480$. However, we need a2 and b2 in the equation. So, we just include them with a zero coefficient. Hope that clears it up. Also, if you have not learnt about Linear Programming, I don't believe you are supposed to use it to solve the problem but I'll let you decide for yourself.

Comment: But what if you use both machines- M1 and M2 for production of A and B in the same day, in that case won't the equation  become wrong. For example, M1 and M2 both are run for 5 hrs for producing A to give us 30A + 37 A and both machines are run again for the rest 3 hours to produce B. In that case, won't  the equation be invalid?

Comment: @SumanSahu If you produce 30A on M1, you use 8*30 = 240 minutes of M1's time. You don't use 5 hours. Similarly, to produce 37A on M2, you only need to run M2 for 37*10 = 370 minutes and not 5 hours.

Comment: i meant to say- 37 A from M1 ie 8*37.5=300 min which is 5 hrs and 30 A from M2 ie 10*30=300 min which is 5 hrs again.So 2 machines working simultaneously for 5 hrs for producing A will give us 67 A. Isnt it?

Comment: @SumanSahu To produce 1 unit of A on M1 takes 8 minutes. To produce 37 units of A on M1 takes 8 * 37 minutes. I don't understand why you got 8*37.5 = 300? You can't produce 0.5 of A.

Comment: of course I can't produce 0.5 of A. I was just asking WHAT IF both the machines were operated for producing only A at a stretch for 5 hours; so i got 300 minutes in hand. Therefore, in those 300 minutes, i would be able to produce a maximum of 67 A only. Also my question remains- both machines- M1 and M2 for production of A and B in the same day, in that case won't the 8a1+0a2+6b1+0b2<=480 equation become wrong?

Comment: @SumanSahu I provided further clarification in the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for pestering you for so many times. I got it.

Comment: @SumanSahu No problem. Glad I was able to help.